# Item touch listener for recycler view

Tags: android, view, click, touch, android-recyclerview

How do i listen for touch events in a recycler view?I have implemented click listener for the view holder but this works on the entire view.I have an image view in each view holder and when the user clicks on an image view i need to perform an action.

```
    public class ViewHolder_Custom extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView name;
    private ImageView image_path;
    private static ClickListener clickListener_custom;

    public ViewHolder_Custom(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        image_path = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public TextView getName() {
        return name;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clickListener_custom != null) {
            clickListener_custom.itemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public ImageView getImage_path() {
        return image_path;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void itemClick(View v, int position);
    }

    public static void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        ViewHolder_Custom.clickListener_custom = clickListener;
    }
}
```

Current View Holder code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to perform action when click every imageview in an item,you can add onClickListener for your imageview of each viewholder.According to the order of performing touch listener,your imageview's listener will perform before the listener added to viewholder.view.

Comment: I have added my current code,currently i am using an interface so i can use that interface in any class that implements the interface and get the click event there,could you tell me what i need to add so that i get the click event for the image and how i can handle that event in any other class.

Comment: Before ` itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` add `image_path.setOnClickListener(***)`,then add the listener to be added to imageview as you want.